# Create iOS app in Kumulos?

Tags: ios, xcode, kumulos

i'm an iOS developer, but newbie to the **kumulos**, after creating app in the **kumulos** website i'm stuck in how to it implement **Xcode**. and the documentation inside the **kumulos**  website isn't rich and helpful for that matter, any advice will be appreciated.

Thank you for you all.

Answer (score 0):

Mark from Kumulos here. Assuming you have [enabled the App Build feature](https://docs.kumulos.com/build/getting-started/), created tables to store your data, created API methods to access your data and then deployed your API methods to the Kumulos API servers. Download your SDK from your Kumulos console and follow these instructions to integrate the SDK into your Xcode project.

1. Unzip the `bindings.zip` file
2. Navigate to the IOS_OSX folder
3. Open your Xcode project
4. Drag and drop the `Kumulos.h`, `Kumulos.m`, and `libKumulos.h` files into your Xcode project.
5. If building for iOS, also add `libKumulos_iOS_vx.x.x.a` to the project. If building for OSX, add `libKumulos_OSX_vx.x.x.a` to the project instead

We've updated our [docs site](https://docs.kumulos.com/integration/ios/) to make this process clearer. For any other queries, please do not hesitate to contact technical support from within your console.

Mark.